# Responsive Menu (Bootstrap) - Buttons inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two Buttons on the right side of my navbar, in the responsive menu the buttons are arranged among themselves.

Is it possible to make the Buttons inline, so the two buttons are on top in the first row.

```
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <p class="navbar-btn btn-space btn-top-space">
                        <a href="https://url.com" target="_blank" title="Customer Payment Panel (CPP)" class="btn-sm btn-info">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> <strong>Customer Panel</strong> (CPP)
                        </a>
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <p class="navbar-btn btn-top-space">
                        <a href="https://url.com" target="_blank" title="Control Panel (Plesk)" class="btn-sm btn-success">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> <strong>Control Panel</strong> (Plesk)
                        </a>
                    </p>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this.

You have to add custom media style.

Css-

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .nav.top-nav  li{
        display:inline-block;
    }
}
```

Html -

```
 <ul class="nav top-nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
        <p class="navbar-btn btn-space btn-top-space">
            <a href="https://url.com" target="_blank" title="Customer Payment Panel (CPP)" class="btn-sm btn-info">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> <strong>Customer Panel</strong> (CPP)
            </a>
        </p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p class="navbar-btn btn-top-space">
            <a href="https://url.com" target="_blank" title="Control Panel (Plesk)" class="btn-sm btn-success">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> <strong>Control Panel</strong> (Plesk)
            </a>
        </p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this may help u

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <span class="navbar-btn btn-space btn-top-space">
                        <a href="https://url.com" target="_blank" title="Customer Payment Panel (CPP)" class="btn-sm btn-info">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> <strong>Customer Panel</strong> (CPP)
                        </a>
                    </span>
                       <span class="navbar-btn btn-top-space">
                        <a href="https://url.com" target="_blank" title="Control Panel (Plesk)" class="btn-sm btn-success">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> <strong>Control Panel</strong> (Plesk)
                        </a>
                    </span>
                </li>
            </ul>
```